# How do I create a dynamic class for a div variable?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I have the following code in an ERB file:

```
<table border="1">
    <% @lists.each do |list| %>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><%= link_to list.title, list %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_list_path(list) %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "Destroy", list_path(list), :method => :delete %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

I want to make the `<tr class="even"` line dynamic. Each `tr` should get the class either "even" or "odd" depending on a counter variable that gets incremented every time my loop starts over. However, I cannot figure out the best way to implement this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this nice helper :)

```
<tr class="<%= cycle("even", "odd") %>">
```